# Create a data extension filtering the All Subscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is there a way to create a data extension using a filter which filters against the Profile Attributes in the All Subscribers List.

I know I can create groups filtering the All Subs List and I can create Data Ext filtering other Data Ext but I haven't seen away to create a Data Ext filtering the Profile Attributes in the All Subs list.

```
SELECT 
SS.EmailAddress,
SS.[Order Submitted Date],
SS.[First order for this Contact],
SS.[Active PG Member],
SS.[LL Kit],
SS.[LL Fed],
SS.[LL State] 

FROM _Subscribers SS 

WHERE SS.Domain = 'YAHOO.COM'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data extension and use an SQL query activity to populate it based on the criteria that you're looking for.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_best_practices_data_extensions_query_activities.htm&type=5

Comment: I'm trying to go after profile attributes which we have created and so far I have been unable to query or retrieve any data using user added attributes. Last attempt I tried putting brackets around the attributes but it just tells me the columns are invalid.                                            SELECT SS.EmailAddress                                                                         ,SS.[Order Submitted Date]
    ,SS.[First order for this Contact]
    ,SS.[Active PG Member]
    ,SS.[LL Kit]
    ,SS.[LL Fed]
    ,SS.[LL State]
FROM _Subscribers SS
WHERE SS.Domain = 'YAHOO.COM'

Comment: Can you add your full query to the post?

Comment: Are the attributes like `First order for this contact` living on the All Subscribers table?